# Remove previous values from array and update with new ones

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my PWA, I'm making http requests and populate flip cards with responses.
Requests depends on selected values.

The problem is: When I select an item from the dropdown menu, it makes the request and show the flip cards populated by that response. But when I select another Item, it makes the request and adds the new cards, without cleaning the view (array) from the previous cards.

> **The searchByIngredient.component.ts**

```
search() {
    this.drinksapi.get(this.selectedIngredient.name).subscribe(data => {
      const a = data[`drinks`];
      a.map((y: { idDrink: any; }) => this.drinksapi.detailsCocktails(y.idDrink).subscribe(res => {
        const b = res[`drinks`];
        for (y of b) {
          const obj = Object.assign({}, y);
          this.onSearch.emit(obj);
        }
      }));
    });
  }
```

> Navbar(dropdown).component.html

```
<ng-select [items]="ingredients"
                   bindLabel="name"
                   placeholder="Search By Ingredient"
                   [(ngModel)]="selectedIngredient"
                   (ngModelChange)="search()">
        </ng-select>
```

> App.Component.ts (probably the problem is in this code)

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'CocktailDB';
  drinks: Array<any> = [];

  onSearch($event: any) {
    // this.drinks.length = 0;
    if (this.drinks !== []) {
      this.drinks.push($event);
    }
    console.log('drinks', this.drinks);
  } // end onSearch
```

[I've noticed also that I'm recieving "Drinks" one by one, here's a screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWDHn.png)

So depends on "this.drinks.length", I'm getting or an array where every new card is merged with the old ones, or it's showing only one card (what it's updated by the selected ingredient)...I can't understand how to resolve this...**I just want to update the view (and Empty the array) every time I select an Item**

Comment: I don't really get what's happening on `searchByIngredient.component.ts` ... try to avoid variable's names such as `y of b` ... If you go back in your code like 1 year later you're going to be lost ! ;)  it seem that you're calling `this.onSearch.emit()` on your loop and that why `this.drinks` is fullfilling one by one ...

Comment: I don't see how onSearch is connected with anything from navbar

Comment: @Seba99 you are definitely right about the variables! I'll change them...I'm looping because actually there are 2 http requests. One is giving me only ID of the drink and the name when i select for example "ingredient" from the dropdown menu. The other request has to loop through the ID's and get the details of each drink

Comment: @Dino they are connected in this way:

<header>
  <app-navbar (onSearch)="onSearch($event)"></app-navbar>
</header>
<body>
<app-cards [arraydrinks]="drinks"></app-cards>
</body>

Comment: Then you must `this.onSearch.emit()` at the end of all API request I think ... Just first build your array with both calls then send the result ... It gonna be less messy :p

Comment: And then just changing `this.drinks.push($event);` by `this.drinks = $event` should maybe solve the problem ... Or first `this.drinks.length = 0;` ( why is this commented ?) and then push ^^

Comment: @Seba99 It's working perfectly! OMG finally! 
thank you for being so kind and patient because I'm a newbie

Comment: You're welcome :) I've posted an aswer too ... Feel free to accept it as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're calling your `this.onSearch.emit()` in your loop so it will be triggered for each drink you have ...

You better first build your array with your 2 API calls and THEN call this `this.onSearch.emit()` to set your `this.drinks` array with : `this.drinks = $event`